# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to show 'panoramaview' in the 'infowindow'.
But I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined' when trying to using 'google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading'.

Can you check What is wrong?

```
var myMap;
var myMarkerList=[];
var myBound;
var myStreetView;
var radius;
var clickedMarker;
var m_mark;

var initMap = function(){
    var myStyleType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyles,{name: 'Styled Map'});
    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        center:{lat:40.7413549, lng:-73.9980244},
        zoom:13,
        mapTypeControlOptions:{
            mapTypeIds:['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
            'styled_map']
        }
    });

    myMap.mapTypes.set('styled_map', myStyleType);
    myMap.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, 'click', function(event){
        setMarkerList(event.latLng);
        openInfoWindow(event.latLng);
    });
    myBound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            m_mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:{lat: 40.7713024, lng: -73.9632393},
            map:myMap,
            title:'Park Ave Penthouse',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            });

            m_mark.addListener('click', function(){
            openStreetView(this);
            clickedMarker = this;
            });


    myStreetView = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    radius = 50;

}

function setMarkerList(pos){
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:pos,
            map:myMap,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });

    myMarker.addListener('click', function(){
        openStreetView(this);
        clickedMarker = this;
    });

    myMarkerList.push(myMarker);

    setBound(myMarker);
}

function openStreetView(targetMarker){

    myStreetView.getPanoramaByLocation(targetMarker.position, radius, getParanomaView);
}

function getParanomaView(data, status){

    var myInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    if (status = google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latlng;

        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(nearStreetViewLocation, clickedMarker.position);
        myInfo.setContent('<div>'+clickedMarker.title+'</div><div id="panorama"></div>');
        var panoramaOptions = {
                    position:nearStreetViewLocation,
                    pov: {
                        heading: heading,
                        pitch: 30
                    }
                };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama( document.getElementById('panorama'),panoramaOptions);
    }
    else{
        myInfo.setContent('<div>'+clickedMarker.title+'</div><div>No Street View Found</div>');
    }
    myInfo.open(myMap, targetMarker);
}
```

I have no hunches anymore as to what may be causing this, so I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: It always helps me to debug by spitting data to the console when I see errors like this add the lines `console.log(nearStreetViewLocation);` `console.log(clickedMarker.position);` above the `computeHeading` line to see what data you are actually trying to send. Some of these google objects are a bear to figure out. (You can see these log lines in the dev console by hitting F12 in the browser)

Comment: You are doing assignment not comparison in `if (status = google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK)`.  I suspect the status is not ok.

Comment: You have a typo: `var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latlng;` should be `var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;`  Most of the other comments/answers are valid as well, but they aren't causing the reported error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review (of other comments), there are a few issues with the `getParanomaView()` function. It should be:

```
function getParanomaView(data, status){
    var myInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;

        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(nearStreetViewLocation, clickedMarker.getPosition());
        myInfo.setContent('<div>'+clickedMarker.title+'</div><div id="panorama"></div>');
        var panoramaOptions = {
            position:nearStreetViewLocation,
            pov: {
                heading: heading,
                pitch: 30
            }
        };
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('panorama'),panoramaOptions);
    } else {
        myInfo.setContent('<div>'+clickedMarker.title+'</div><div>No Street View Found</div>');
    }
    myInfo.open(myMap, targetMarker);
}
```

**Previous Answer**

The line `var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(nearStreetViewLocation, clickedMarker.position);`

should be

`var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(nearStreetViewLocation, clickedMarker.getPosition());`

Otherwise the `clickedMarker.position` would be undefined.